# Auto completado de País -> Estado -> Municipio

Tags: html, base-de-datos

como puedo hacer para hacer un select que me muestre la continuación de los estados y después sus ciudades, lo que tengo hasta este momento es un input dentro de un div para agregarlo manualmente ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Ejemplo:

Pais: Canada, Estados Unidos, **Mexico**

Estado: Baja California, **Sinaloa**, Jalisco

Cuidad: **Mazatlan**, Culiacan, Los mochis

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Origen y Destino</h3>
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pais Origen</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="porigen" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado Origen</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="eorigen" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad Origen</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="corigen" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pais Destino</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="pdestino" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado Destino</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="edestino" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad Destino</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="cdestino" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: te sugiero empezar a investigar por aqui: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

Comment: La verdad estoy investigando ya que nunca lo he hecho eso, solo el select basico (select -> option -> value="1") pues agrega el valor pero que los select dependan de otros nunca, estoy checando esta pag. https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/combos-dependientes-con-jquery-ajax-y-php/